# How to generate network traffic and save it to pcap files?

Tags: linux, snort, scapy

I want to test *snort*, so I want to have some test network traffic. Since *snort* can read pcap files, I want to generate some traffics which can be customized and save it to pcap files. Here are my questions:

1. Is it right to test *snort* as I said?
2. Is there a good tool to generate traffic and save it to pcap file?

   Any suggestions about what I going to do means a lot to me!

Comment: `tcpdump` is able to generate pcap files for you.

Comment: One more question, is *Scapy* OK? @RuiFRibeiro

Comment: Scapy is a very interesting library for people who has programming abilities. No idea if it generates pcap files easily.

Answer (score 2):

`tcpdump` works very well, but can have an issue if you create your `pcap` incorrectly.

```
tcpdump -i ens18 -w example.pcap
```

`-i` specifies the interface and mine was `ens18`;
`-w` specifies the file.

Note there are no limits set to this `tcpdump`, meaning you have to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> to complete it.

Instead of manually stopping you could use `-C` for file size limit or `-c` for packet count.